# node.js - using .map to enrich object

Tags: node.js

I have an object (set of product data), within some of those objects I have an array of images. For each of the images I need to call an API to get extra data, then I want to put this back into the original object.

The API call is by ID, that's working and I can get the data.

I think I have a problem with the async nature and I am missing something (probably obvious!)...

Thanks!

```
    function fetchImages(products) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();
    var product_updates = [];

    products.forEach(function (product, idx, array) {

        var image_updates = [];

        if (product.images.length > 0)
        {
            //var id = product.images.mediaId;
            //console.log(id);
            image_updates = product.images.map(function(task) {
                return {
                    image_urls: getImage(task.mediaId)
                }
            });

            console.log(image_updates);
            product_updates.push(image_updates);

        }
        else
        {
            product_updates.push(product);
        }

        if (idx === array.length - 1)
        {
            //console.log(stock_updates);
            deferred.resolve(product_updates);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Here is the shortened "getImage" function...

```
function getImage(id)
{
    // Request options
    var options = {
        url: cfg.base_url + (cfg.base_url[cfg.base_url.length - 1] != '/' ? '/' : '') + 'api/media/' + id,
        .........
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {

            // Check status code
            if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {

                let result = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(result);
                return result;

            } else {
                console.log("Failed to fetch images updates");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I'm also unsure if "deferred.resolve(product_updates);" is done correctly.. seems to work but not 100% sure.

console.log for "image_update" returns:

```
[ { image_urls: undefined },
  { image_urls: undefined },
  { image_urls: undefined },
  { image_urls: undefined },
  { image_urls: undefined } ]
```

************ Amended fetchImages() function ***********

```
    function fetchImages(products) {

    const getImagesForProduct = function(product) {
        return product.images.map(function(task) {
            return {
                product: product,
                image_urls: getImage(task.mediaId)
            }
        });
    }

    const product_updates = products.map(getImagesForProduct)

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        resolve(product_updates);
    });

}
```

This is more eloquent now... but still not got the promise needed?

Comment: 1. you don't need to check the length of the array prior to running map on it.  It will not MAP if there are no elements (a null check is another story)

Comment: 2. are you sure you are resolving?

Comment: ok, removed the check on length.. that was from previous attempts.

Comment: The issue is definitely that the "getImage" is not returning and result. I need to put into promise chain but can't work out how?

Comment: 3. instead of mapping over products - reduce over products and map internally.  the results of the reduce should be the bit that is returned

Comment: well, getImage doesn't return anything - which is why you are getting undefined.  You need to wrap the "request" bit into a promise and return that.  If this is running on the server I would use native promises rather than Q for my promise handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you example getImage makes and asynchronous call and therefore should return a promise.  Many ways to return a promise - but the native promise object is the easiest (i suspect you could do this with Q too - but it has been a long time since I used that library).

```
function getImage(id)
{
    // Request options
    var options = {
        url: cfg.base_url + (cfg.base_url[cfg.base_url.length - 1] != '/' ? '/' : '') + 'api/media/' + id,
        .........
    };

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {

            // Check status code
            if (response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {

                let result = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log(result);
                resolve(result);

            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

The other function could be written more eloquently too. Essentially:

```
// :: Product -> [{image_urls: Promise}] 
const getImagesForProduct = function(product) {
       return product.images.map(function(task) {
            return {
                image_urls: getImage(task.mediaId)
            }
        });
}

const product_updates = products.map(getImagesForProduct)
//=> [[{image_urls: Promise}]]
```

In this scenario you still need to wait on the promises to resolve.  I suspect you could flatten the array or restructure the transformations to be less hairy - but it depends on what your other code *needs*

Comment: I still get "Promise pending" on the console log.. which is closer that before!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final function that deals with the promises:

```
function fetchImages(products) {

const getImagesForProduct = function(product) {

    if (product.images && product.images.length === 0) {

        return Promise.resolve(product)
    }

    const getImagesPromiseTasks = product.images.map(task => getImage(task.mediaId));

    return Promise.all(getImagesPromiseTasks)
        .then(retrievedUrls => {
                product.image_urls = retrievedUrls
                return product
            })
}

return Promise.all(products.map(getImagesForProduct))
```

}